# Постраничная навигация без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript

Имееться код:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) { ?>
        <?php if ($i == $active_page) { ?>
        <span>
          <?= $i ?>
        </span>
<?php } else { ?>
        <a href="?page=<?= $i ?>">
          <?= $i ?>
        </a>
       <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

1-2 страница
Как сделать пагинацию без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Без ajax - никак.

Comment: AJAX + PushState (pjax)